# Vala int.parse crashing

Tags: vala

I want to build a simple Tool to check for SVN revision number changes ( = someone committed), but I'm stuck at a very strange issue.
When I compile and run my code, the first of the following messages gets printed, the next doesn't:

```
while (true) {
    var msg = new Soup.Message("GET", this.repo.URL);
    session.send_message(msg);
    MatchInfo matchInfo;
    pattern.match((string)msg.response_body.data, 0, out matchInfo);
    var revisionString = matchInfo.fetch_named("revision");
    stdout.printf("Current Revision: [%s]\n", revisionString);
    var currentRevision = int.parse("383");
    stdout.printf("Current Revision parsed %d", currentRevision);
    Thread.usleep(150000000);
}
```

I inserted the hardcoded string `"383"` just for testing, but it still fails.
I can't see anything wrong with the printf's either, and there are no compiler errors.
If it would help, I could post some more code.

Answer (score 1):

`int.parse` just calls `atoi`. You can verify this by looking at the generated C.

`atoi` is not thread-safe and I'm assuming you're running this in multiple threads due to your `Thread.usleep`.

Use `int64.try_parse` instead, which is based on `strtoll`.

Also, try a more minimal test case not involving the `this.repo.LastRevision`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change anything. But I just found out that adding stdout.flush() solves the problem with the debug messages I inserted.

Comment: Can you post a minimal case with the problem? Because `int.parse("383")` alone works for me.